# Spring boot - is there a way to disable AOP for a given profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have been having issues with AOP when running the build and/or running tests. I tried to annotate the `@Aspect` class with `@Profile("local", "war")` to make sure that aspect is only accessible to the "local" and "war" profiles, but a scenario might incur when we need to add that aspect support to another profile. And we prefer not to have this hard-coded there.

Is there a clean way to forbid, for instance, the "test" profile to access a given aspect class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, aspects are treated as beans in spring:

If its only about "create aspect only if not in profile test", then you can merely go with:

```
@Profile("!test")
```

If you want a more sophisticated condition, then keep reading:

Spring profiles were introduced in Spring 3.x but in 4.x the were rewritten with more flexible conditionals.

Take a look at `@Profile` source code:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(ProfileCondition.class)
public @interface Profile {

    /**
     * The set of profiles for which the annotated component should be registered.
     */
    String[] value();

}
```

Note the `@Conditional` with `ProfileCondition` as an implementation of "evaluation" logic.

This class's implementation is pretty straightforward.

You can create your custom annotation like a profile that will call a similar evaluation logic.